# How to Drag/Drop Material-UI Cards

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to drag/drop and change the sorting of the Material UI Cards? If so, how?
https://material-ui.com/components/cards/

Comment: I asked inherently (within the library of material-ui). My question is more like Is it possible to bike to mars then in this case, there is no way, based on my understanding...

Comment: Why is it so difficult to, without arguing, say what you know, and that's it. My question is not vague in any way. I just genuinely want to know if anyone knew.

Comment: Sorry if I was rude about the `mars` question. I was just trying to show that your question could be better or that you could have tried searching more before asking.

Comment: I get your point. I did google and didn't find material-ui supporting drag-drop for cards itself without any other library so I wanted to ask to see if I missed anything. 3rd party libraries, there is way, I know, thank you tho.

Comment: Stackoverflow would be a much more useful resource if the denizens were less eager to attack perfectly reasonable and valuable questions. Just saying.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Is it possible to drag/drop and change the sorting of the Material UI Cards/

Yes.

> how?

You can use [`react-dnd`](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/) or [`react-beautiful-dnd`](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd).

They have alot of examples on how to do it and you can check it [here for react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples).

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-beaver-vv5jo) of how to do it and, which is based on react-dnd examples.

And this is what `react-beautiful-dnd` has to say about both options:

> There are a lot of libraries out there that allow for drag and drop
> interactions within React. Most notable of these is the amazing
> react-dnd. It does an incredible job at providing a great set of drag
> and drop primitives which work especially well with the wildly
> inconsistent html5 drag and drop feature. react-beautiful-dnd is a
> higher level abstraction specifically built for lists (vertical,
> horizontal, movement between lists, nested lists and so on). Within
> that subset of functionality react-beautiful-dnd offers a powerful,
> natural and beautiful drag and drop experience. However, it does not
> provide the breadth of functionality offered by react-dnd. So
> react-beautiful-dnd might not be for you depending on what your use
> case is.

Comment: I don't know... `react-beautiful-dnd` seems to fall apart for me as soon as I try to use MaterialUI's styling. I tried `withStyles`, `makeStyles`, and their "styled components". Immediate failure of the draggable feature as soon as I called any of those.

Comment: @MikeTwo so that's probably a conflict on how material ui and the dnd library styles the components. There's probably a way of making both work together.

Comment: I assume it's a version problem -- I'm on "^3.9.2" -- but I've seen sandboxes where it works with 4.12.3. So ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Found this new library [@dnd-kit/core](https://dndkit.com/). Looks nice and has lots of options. You can check examples [here](https://examples.dndkit.com/)